# isset() multiple parameters difference

Tags: php, isset, difference

What is the difference between

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']) && !isset($_GET['lang'])) return 'ru';
```

and

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang'], $_GET['lang'])) return 'ru';
```

Why does the first one work correctly, but the second always return 'ru'?
As I understand the two conditions are equivalent, but why do they work differently under the same conditions?

Without session and get parameter the first version returns nothing (as I need it), but the second version always returns true, not matter if any of the parameters are set or not.

Comment: Are `$_SESSION['lang']` and `$_GET['lang']` set before the if?

Answer (score 2):

First condition means both of them have to be set

```
if (! isset($_SESSION['lang']) && ! isset($_GET['lang']))
```

Second condition:

`isset($_SESSION['lang'], $_GET['lang']` means: `both are set`.

`!(isset($_SESSION['lang'], $_GET['lang'])` means: `at least one is unset`

So if the `$_SESSION['lang']` is set and `$_GET['lang']` is not set, the second condition will display `ru`

Answer (score 1):

> If multiple parameters are supplied then `isset()` will return `TRUE` only
>   if all of the parameters are set. Evaluation goes from left to right
>   and stops as soon as an unset variable is encountered.

This means that `isset(A,B)` is the same as `isset(A) && isset(B)`.

Therefore your second version

```
!isset(A,B)
```

is equivalent to

```
!(isset(A) && isset(B))
```

which is equivalent to

```
!isset(A) || !isset(B)  // DeMorgan
```

which is **NOT** equivalent to your first version

```
!isset(A) && !isset(B)
```

Comment: So there is no way, that would not duplicate word 'isset' ?
And if i want to do something, only when i dont have two, or three, or four for example variables, i need to write only something like 
  
    `!isset(A) && !isset(B) && !isset(C) && !isset(D)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect condition.
You can use any of these 3 conditions.

```
if ((!isset($i)) || (!isset($j))) echo 'ru1';
if (!(isset($i) && isset($j))) echo 'ru3';
if (!isset($i,$j)) echo 'ru2';
```